# Getting error 1136 in this MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I get a 1136 error (Column count does not match value count at row 1) here. How can I fix this?

```
INSERT INTO salesrep (Sreopno, Srepname, Srepstreet, Srepcity, Srepprov, Sreppcode, Totcomm, Commrate)
Values ('NKO5', 'Celina', '48', 'Furrows End', 'Brampton', 'ON', 'L6Z4S5', '300.00', '0.20');
```

Answer (score 2):

you have 8 columns and you are inserting 9 values , you misssed one column.

The error message clearly said it `COLUM COUNT DOES NOT MATCH VALUE COUNT`

- check in your database for spaces if you have in the right of left of your column names
  in your code `Sreopno`

you can also check for spaces like that

```
    INSERT INTO salesrep (`Sreopno `, Srepname,..
                                  ^---space here
```

or

```
    INSERT INTO salesrep (` Sreopno`, Srepname,
                           ^--space here
```

Comment: thank you ,,,,,,,,but now i got another error 1054  which says "unknown column 'srepno' in 'field list'. 1054

Comment: i dont know what is the right you used in your code `Sreopno` and then now you said `srepno` please check which is right

Comment: i made these changes :                                          INSERT INTO salesrep(Sreopno, Srepname, Srepstreet, Srepcity, Srepprov, Sreppcode, Totcomm, Commrate)
Values ('NKO5', 'Celina', '48 Furrows End', 'Brampton', 'ON', 'L6Z4S5', '300.00', '0.20');

Comment: check in your database and in your query if its `Sreopno` or `srepno` because i see you got error with that columns name but you using different column.

Comment: the error is like this: "unknown column 'sreopno' in 'field list'. 1054

Comment: its with `sreopno` or with `Sreopno` , make attention between small s and big S

Comment: then check your database if its exact name and also check if there is space near of `Sreopno ` , please look if there is space in the right or in left of `Sreopno` in database.

Comment: I am unable to find any error; WELL THIS IS THE COPY PASTE OF MY DATABASE:                                                         INSERT INTO salesrep(Sreopno, Srepname, Srepstreet, Srepcity, Srepprov, Sreppcode, Totcomm, Commrate)
Values ('NKO5', 'Celina', 'Furrows End', 'Brampton', 'ON', 'L6Z4S5', '300.00', '0.20');

Comment: dude ! please check your column name in your table in your phpmyadmin. not the query . this query is good. check for spaces as i told in the column name `Sreopno` look in right and in left if there is space remove it. ,

Comment: edit your table and check the name of this column if you have space , just move cursor by -> to the right and see if it goes or not , if it goes means you have space ,  remove it.

Comment: dude , i cant see verify this with you , unknown column `Sreopno` so please check it in your query in your database ,check spaces big or small letters ..etc, glad it solved your main problem .

Comment: check edited answer and check with those columns names with spaces and see which one is right , if one of them works means you have space .